# Where are Vue 2's ComponentDefinition and ComponentConstructor types defined?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I want to add a dynamic Vue 2 `component` and have it correctly typed in TypeScript. The [documentation clearly states](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/?redirect=true#component) that `is` takes `string | ComponentDefinition | ComponentConstructor`, but I can find neither of those custom types. My IDE also presents an error with those types, so they must come from somewhere (which may be a language plugin and not anything in the codebase). I've grepped through my `node_modules` and searched both the Vue and DefinitelyTyped repositories. Where are these types defined?

Relevant portions of my SFC:

```html
<ItemComponent
    v-for="(item, index) in myItems"
    :key="`${item.name}-${index}`"
>
    <component :is="item.icon"></component>
</ItemComponent>
```

```js
import {Component, Vue} from 'vue-property-decorator';
import IconCreditCard from '...';
import IconGiftCard from '...';

interface IItem {
    name: string;
    icon: string | unknown; // here's the type in question
};

@Component({
    components: {
        IconCreditCard,
        IconGiftCard,
        ...
    }
})
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
    myItems: Array<IItem> = [
        {
            name: 'Gift Card',
            icon: IconGiftCard,
        },
        {
            name: 'Credit Card',
            icon: IconCreditCard,
        },
    ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue documentation isn't generated from TypeScript types, these are pseudo-types.

Vue has [`Component` type](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/v2.7.14/types/options.d.ts#L15) that refers to some Vue component and corresponds to `ComponentDefinition | ComponentConstructor` part.

Comment: That the documentation uses pseudo-types is disappointing. I can't use `Component` because it conflicts with the decorator from `vue-property-decorator` (and I really don't want to get in the pattern of aliasing one or the other). The `Component` type is an alias for `typeof Vue`, which gives errors when used on its own.

Comment: Can you clarify what's the problem with vue-property-decorator? The question doesn't mention this. I'm not sure which one you referred but Vue's `Component` is more than `typeof Vue`

Comment: Is the problem that there are two Component imports? You can import one of them under a different name

Comment: "I really don't want to get in the pattern of aliasing one or the other", but I suppose I could create a single type alias somewhere and import that.

Comment: I see what you meant. Sounds about right, can be `Component as ComponentType` then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252973/discussion-between-nshew13-and-estus-flask).

Comment: Sorry, I don't use chats on SO, I get no notifications on messages. So it appears ComponentDefinition type is really used somewhere on your side. Does the error occur when you use a component with `is`? Probably is specific to IDE, or more specifically the plugin that adds Vue support. Is it VSC+Volar?

Comment: Example updated. IDE is PhpStorm with the bundled Vue.js plugin.

Comment: Indeed, https://github.com/JetBrains/web-types/blob/master/packages/vue/vue%403.0.0.web-types.json#L23 seems to be the only meaningful mention of this type besides the docs. Then I'm quite sure the problem is specific to Jetbrains, you can try to check a new IDE version if it's not already or try to solve it via tracker or ask a question, they are active on SO. Any way, the correct type for what you're trying to achieve is `string | Component`.