# Proper Type for Vue Imported Component to use with the Dynamic Component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to pass a component through props to be rendered using the `<Component :is="">` component, but can't seem to figure out the right types to be using.

Type definition is as follows

```
import type { Component } from "vue";

export interface GridColumn {
    // not relevant stuff here
    component?: Component,
}
```

Then within my component I have, the following, which has no complaints at this point.

```
import Severity from "@/modules/playground/grid-columns/Severity.vue";
import type { DataRow, GridColumn } from "@/components/grid/grid-column.type";

const columns: GridColumn[] = [
    {
        component: Severity,
    }
];
```

But when I get into the actual usage rendering it gives a type error, but still renders as expected.

```
<template>
    <Component 
        v-if="col.component" 
        :is="col.component"
    ></Component>
</template>
```

The `is` property line above is highlighted in my editor (PHPStorm 2023.1) as an error:

> Type (ComponentOptionsBase<any, any, any, ComputedOptions, MethodOptions, any, any, any> & ThisType<CreateComponentPublicInstance<{}, any, any, ComputedOptions, MethodOptions, any, any, any, Readonly>>) | FunctionalComponent<any, any> | ComponentPublicInstanceConstructor is not assignable to type string | ComponentDefinition

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75930018 . The type is correct. It's the problem that is specific to Jetbrains IDE. Consider checking with their support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the IDE issue, please follow [WEB-60065](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-60065/Vue3-dynamic-component-type-mismatch-errors-when-using-component-ref-as-is-prop-value) and linked tickets for updates